# Run linux command within sublime plugin

Tags: sublimetext2

I am currently writing a simple plugin for Sublime Text 2 to make a shortcut, running pdflatex program with my opened file as an option. 
So there is a question: is there any way to run linux command from sublime? I haven't found appropriate function in Plugin API Reference.

Comment: There is this guy who wrote a Sublime plugin for running arbitary shell commands - https://github.com/misfo/Shell-Turtlestein. You can look at his code and try to figure how he runs the commands.

Comment: why not just use a [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html)?